# Spring @Cachable updating data

Tags: java, database, spring, caching

example from : [SpringSource](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-petclinic/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/samples/petclinic/service/ClinicServiceImpl.java)

```
@Cacheable(value = "vets")
public Collection<Vet> findVets() throws DataAccessException {
    return vetRepository.findAll();
}
```

How does `findVets()` work exactly ?

For the first time, it takes the data from `vetRepository` and saves the result in cache. But what happens if a new vet is inserted in the database - does the cache update (out of the box behavior) ? If not, can we configure it to update ?

---

**EDIT:**

But what happens if the DB is updated from an external source (e.g. an application which uses the same DB) ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
@CachePut("vets")    
public void save(Vet vet) {..}
```

You have to tell the cache that an object is stale. If data change without using your service methods then, of course, you would have a problem. You can, however, clear the whole cache with

```
@CacheEvict(value = "vets", allEntries = true)    
public void clearCache() {..}
```

It depends on the Caching Provider though. If another app updates the database without notifying your app, but it uses the same cache it, then the other app would probably update the cache too.

Comment: can they share the same Caching Provider ?

Comment: In theory: Yes. But it would be necessary that the cache runs as a separate application. The Spring default provider is just a simple map.

Comment: When I use `@CacheEvict` on *save/update* methods and `@Cacheable` on *findAll* it works fine as answered. When I tried `@CachePut` which *always causes the method to be invoked and its result to be stored in the associated cache* on save/update does not return the updated records. Can you please share your thoughts on the same

Comment: Why is this accepted answer?
Question was not to update data not how to clear it so it is populated when method is called again. IMHO

Answer (score 0):

It would not do it automatically and there is not way for the cache to know if the data has been externally introduced.

Check `@CacheEvict` which will help you invalidate the cache entry in case of any change to the underlying collections.

```
@CacheEvict(value = "vet", allEntries = true)
public void saveVet() {
  // Intentionally blank
}
```

> **allEntries**
>   Whether or not all the entries inside the cache(s) are removed or not.
>   By default, only the value under the associated key is removed.   Note that specifying setting this parameter to true and specifying a key is not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

you also can use @CachePut on the method which creates the new entry. The return type has to be the same as in your @Cachable method.

```
@CachePut(value = "vets")
public Collection<Vet> updateVets() throws DataAccessException {
    return vetRepository.findAll();
}
```

In my opinion an exernal service has to call the same methods.